# Printing the size of each element in a nested list with numbers and strings

Tags: python, nested-lists

When I try to run the following for loop I get an error.

```
TypeError: object of type 'int' has no len()
```

Desired output: `1 1 3 3`

This is the code that I am trying to run. Thanks to everyone who can help me with this question!

```py
lst = ['spam!', 1, ['Brie', 'Roquefort', 'Pol lê Veq'], [1, 2, 3]]

for index in lst:
    print(len(index))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, you need to check whether each item is a list. Then, you apply the `len` function to the items that are lists and print out the result, otherwise, print out `1`.

```py
lst = ['spam!', 1, ['Brie', 'Roquefort', 'Pol lê Veq'], [1, 2, 3]]

for i in lst:
    if isinstance(i, list):
        print(len(i))
    else:
        print(1)
```

Comment: I didn't know the python "isinstance()" function yet, as I'm reading a book I'm learning I didn't know it completely, but it solved my problem the way I wanted to, thank you very much

Comment: Done, first time publishing something in stackoverflow xD

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that you cannot get the character length of an integer in python, you could either turn each item into a list.

```
list = [['spam!'], [1], ['Brie', 'Roquefort', 'Pol lê Veq'], [1, 2, 3]]

for index in list:
    print(len(index))
```

Or you could use a string instead of an integer and cast it when needed.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but I wanted a more direct answer to the problem without having to mess with the list, and the answer from the colleague above does what I want. But thanks anyway

Comment: It's sort of unavoidable, you could cast the value to string if it is not a list.

Comment: I'm not sure that it's sort of unavoidable, because like i said, with the function isinstance(). I don't necessarily need to convert everything to string because it compares and returns the result I want, so I can have everything in strings, I can have integers or a mix but i understand your point of view.